# Jquery listbox with input field

Tags: jquery, listbox

I have a dropdown listbox and each time the user selects an item I copy that item below.  They can select up to ten items.  I've seen lots of code for selecting multiple items from one list box to another.  That would be great, but I need to have an input field available with the item selected.  So when they pick one and it copies to the selected list, they need to be able to enter an amount.  These are charities, if I pick charity one, I need to add how much I would like to donate to charity one.

charity one        charity one   |**50_**|

charity two

charity three

.
If anyone knows a way to do this, please share.  Thank you in advance...
Serena :-)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id="selectBox" style="height:225px;width:100px" multiple="multiple">
</select>

<div id="tableDiv">
    <form>
    <table id="dynamicTable">

    </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
var select = $("#selectBox");
for (var i = 0, max = 20; i < max; i++){
    var option = $("<option></option>").text("hello"+i);
    select.append(option);
}

select.change(function() {
    var str = "";
    var table = $("#dynamicTable");
    table.empty();
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
        var optionText = $(this).text();
        var row = $("<tr></tr>").append("<input type='text' placeholder='"+optionText+"'>");
        table.append(row);
    });
});
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/tPZyj/

Other things (max of 10 selected, enhancements, styling) are left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @user3182230 No problem!  If it helps you please use the checkmark to mark my answer as accepted :)